# What is the array size in this declaration

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

```
extern unsigned char pkt_data[];
```

Here what will be the `pkt_data` size. How do I know the `pkt_data` declaration?

Comment: Have you tried running that and seeing its output?

Answer (score 2):

All that the declaration says is that there's an array named `pkt_data`.  The size is not specified there, and unless you're the one writing that line, the specifics of it should be left to the code that actually defines it (ie: reserves space for it).

Answer (score 1):

It is `extern` declaration. It is declaration only, not definition.

It means `pkt_data` will be defined in some other file or some other modules being linked.

So, see the definition of `pkt_data` to see its size.

Comment: The main issue her ein terms of getting `pkt_data`'s siez isn't that it's `decalred `extern  but that its declaration is **incomplete**. It is not possible to determine the size of such a type.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the size, extern corresponds that you will define pkt_data[] some where else but only once. you cant get the size from an extern declaration.

Comment: Is perfectly possible to get the size of some `extern` declared variable. It's not the `extern` declaration which makes it impossible to determine the size of the variable declared in this question. It's that the declaration is **incomplete** due to the `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration

```
extern unsigned char pkt_data[];
```

as well as this one

```
unsigned char pkt_data[];
```

are **incomplete**.

It is not possible to determine the size of an **incomplete** type.

---

> How do I know the pkt_data declaration?

You know it.

```
extern unsigned char pkt_data[];
```

is the declaration.

What is missing here is the **definition**.

To answer the question: Search it in the sources available. It you do not have access to the **definition** of `pkt_data` there is no chance to determine the size of `pkt_data`.

All we know is that the address of `pkt_data` would have the siez of a pointer.  The following statement would be perfectly valid, btw:

```
size_t s = sizeof(&pkt_data);
```